# Make a connection to ASI Granite

Tags: java

I need to make a connection to the Granite Database using the ASI installed on the WebLogic application server 10.3.6.
The programming language is Java:

```
 public void connect() throws Exception {
                 if (prop != null) {
                       ConnectionFactoryASI.setProtocol(prop);
                       ConnectionFactoryASI.setDataObjectFactoryType(prop);
                       serviceFactory = ConnectionFactoryASI.getServiceFactory(prop);
                 } else {
                       serviceFactory = ConnectionFactoryASI.getServiceFactory(user);
                 }
                 dataObjectFactory = serviceFactory.getDataObjectFactory();
                setUser(serviceFactory.getClientSession().getLoginName());
                 logger.debug("ASI HostName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getHostName()
                              + ", DatabaseName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getDatabaseName()
                              + ", DbHostName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getDbHostName());
        }
```

It does not connect and gives me a connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ASI need a connection ticketName, without which you can not open a connection.

Here is the correct code, I added the parameter written above:

```
public void connect(String ticketName) throws Exception {
             if (prop != null) {
                   ConnectionFactoryASI.setProtocol(prop);
                   ConnectionFactoryASI.setDataObjectFactoryType(prop);
                   serviceFactory = ConnectionFactoryASI.getServiceFactory(prop, ticketName);
             } else {
                   serviceFactory = ConnectionFactoryASI.getServiceFactory(ticketName, user);
             }
             dataObjectFactory = serviceFactory.getDataObjectFactory();
            setUser(serviceFactory.getClientSession().getLoginName());
             logger.debug("ASI HostName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getHostName()
                          + ", DatabaseName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getDatabaseName()
                          + ", DbHostName: " + serviceFactory.getClientSession().getDbHostName());
      }
```